# How do I change the priority of a process?

Tags: delphi, win32-process

Can anyone provide a Delphi example of code that changes the priority class of a process?

I need to get the process by name from the Windows XP Task manager and change its priority using delphi code.

Comment: How do you plan to identify the process?

Answer (score 12):

you must use the [SetPriorityClass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686219%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

This function is part of the windows unit, this is a sample

```
SetPriorityClass(GetCurrentProcess(), HIGH_PRIORITY_CLASS);
```

Comment: Wow, I never heard about this possibility, +10 if I can :)

Comment: @TLama, altering the priority of a process is a bad idea without an extremely good reason, as it can delay (or kill) OS functionality. Rodrigo didn't point that out, but I'm sure he knew that as well. :) Rodrigo, +1.

Comment: ok. tnx. But if i have in the Task manager (Windows) process "prog.exe" how do i change the priority of this process using this function?

Comment: or i have to use other method?

Comment: You can refer to John Ayres book entitled **The Tomes of Delphi Win32 Core API** (ISBN 1-55622-750-7). It's a must.

Comment: @St.Anger_Roman, to use this function with a file name , you must take an Snapshot of the Running Processes using the [CreateToolhelp32Snapshot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682489%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function, then you must search for the name of the process which you want to change and finally open the process to get a handle (this is the handle which you must pass to the `SetPriorityClass` function) using the [OpenProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684320%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) passing the `PROCESS_SET_INFORMATION` value as parameter.